# R cran sf create a polygon from two sewed shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

My final aim is to create a map of the Vermeille Coast in order to calculate the distance between two sampling points with the condition that the path between the two points is not crossing the land.

To do so:

1/ I took two shapefiles (you can download them here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hzsdklnmvjg4hsz/AAATHLV0pkJXDvSqyRIBlVl_a?dl=0)

2/ I sew them according to : [R cran: sf Sew two MULTILINESTRING/LINESTRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544156/r-cran-sf-sew-two-multilinestring-linestring)

3/ try to create the associated polygons according to that: [Sf package: Close a polygon fom complex shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532869/sf-package-close-a-polygon-fom-complex-shape)

The script is the following:

```
frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls <- st_read("coasts_subnational/coasts_subnational.shp")
spainCoast_CoteBanyuls <- st_read("coasts_subnational SPAIN/coasts_subnational.shp")

combined_coast <- rbind(spainCoast_CoteBanyuls, frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls) 
plot(combined_coast$geometry)
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

which is correct so far. I just need now to create the associated polygon:

```
bbox_combined_coast <- st_bbox(combined_coast) %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

polygon_combined_coast <- bbox_combined_coast %>% 
  lwgeom::st_split(combined_coast) %>% 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

par(mfrow = c(2,4), mar = c(0,0,0,0))
for(i in 1:8){
  plot(polygon_combined_coast[i], col = 'steelblue')
}
```

which gave:

[image]

None of these polygons represents the shape of combined maps above.

Nevertheless, when I plot the polygon from every single shapefile:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2), mar = c(0,0,0,0))

bbox_frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls <- st_bbox(frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls) %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

polygon_frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls <- bbox_frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls %>% 
  lwgeom::st_split(frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls) %>% 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

plot(polygon_frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls[1], col = 'steelblue')

bbox_spainCoast_CoteBanyuls <- st_bbox(spainCoast_CoteBanyuls) %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

polygon_spainCoast_CoteBanyuls <- bbox_spainCoast_CoteBanyuls %>% 
  lwgeom::st_split(spainCoast_CoteBanyuls) %>% 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

plot(polygon_spainCoast_CoteBanyuls[3], col = 'steelblue')
```

It gave:

[image]

these two polygons are correctly shaping the polygon associated to each shapefile.

It seems that rbinding the two shapefiles makes something not expected.
Do you have an idea of the mistake ?

Thanks in advance,

Charlotte

Comment: did you try to use `st_combine()`?

Comment: Hello and Thanks D. J ! 
I actually uses st_union after creating the two polygons, and it seems to work. However, my question was to understand why I could not merge the two "lines" to have only one single line and then create the single polygon. Is this approach counterintuitive ?

Comment: For me it is, I would connect the polygons instead of the lines. But if you have the academic drive to connect the lines maybe you can do something like ths: convert both your lines to `multipoint`, bind them together and then recreate a line from the multipoints. something like this: `lapply(pt_lst, function(x) x %>% st_sf() %>% st_cast("MULTIPOINT") %>% st_union() %>% st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% st_sf()) %>% data.table::rbindlist()`

Comment: Ok I understand this. However why would you convert lines as points ? How did you know you cannot merge two lines ? why lines are such a problem ?

Comment: it should be possible to connect lines. i just had a similar problem where the lines would not meet - there were sub mm gaps over which the lines could not connect. if the lines meet each other perfectly (endpoint of l1 == startpoint of l2) it may not be necessary to create multipoints (it is imho just safer)

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thanks a lot D.J for the feedback !

Answer (score 1):

To combine the two coast lines summarize with no grouping variable
`combined_coast <- rbind(spainCoast_CoteBanyuls, frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls) %>% summarise()` 
Note that it will always be a MULTILINESTRING because there are several small islands off the coast so cannot be a single LINESTRING

can turn that into polygons with
`combined_coast_poly<- combined_coast %>% st_cast("POLYGON")`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both coastlines does not touch, that's why the polygon approach doesn't work.

See here a solution, where I merge the two main coastlines, add the small islands in Spain and try the approach you provided:

```r
# Download files
spainurl <- "https://geo.vliz.be/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&service=wfs&version=1.0.0&typename=MarineRegions:coasts_subnational&outputformat=SHAPE-ZIP&filter=%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3CPropertyName%3Emrgid_1%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3E3417%3C%2FLiteral%3E%3C%2FPropertyIsEqualTo%3E"
download.file(spainurl, "spain.zip", mode = "wb")
unzip("spain.zip", exdir = "spain", junkpaths = TRUE)

franceurl <- "https://geo.vliz.be/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&service=wfs&version=1.0.0&typename=MarineRegions:coasts_subnational&outputformat=SHAPE-ZIP&filter=%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3CPropertyName%3Emrgid_1%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3E19888%3C%2FLiteral%3E%3C%2FPropertyIsEqualTo%3E"
download.file(franceurl, "france.zip", mode = "wb")
unzip("france.zip", exdir = "france", junkpaths = TRUE)

library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
spainCoast_CoteBanyuls <- list.files("spain",
                                     pattern = "shp$",
                                     full.names = TRUE) %>% st_read()
frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls <- list.files("france",
                                      pattern = "shp$",
                                      full.names = TRUE) %>% st_read()
ggplot(spainCoast_CoteBanyuls) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls)
```

[image]

Ok, now extract every single `LINESTRING` of the object. France only has 1.

```r
# A. Decompose in linestrings

lines_spain <- st_geometry(spainCoast_CoteBanyuls) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")
spainCoast_l <- st_sf(n = as.character(seq_len(length(lines_spain))), lines_spain)

ggplot(spainCoast_l) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = n), size = 3)
```

[image]

```r
lines_france <- st_geometry(frenchCoast_CoteBanyuls) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")
franceCoast_l <- st_sf(n = as.character(seq_len(length(lines_france))), lines_france)

ggplot(franceCoast_l) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = n), size = 3)
```

[image]

See if France and Spain touches (spoiler: no)

```r
st_touches(lines_france, lines_spain, sparse = FALSE)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Lines doesn't touch. Merge both main coastlines
spainmax <- spainCoast_l[which.max(st_length(spainCoast_l)), ]
spainrest <- spainCoast_l[-which.max(st_length(spainCoast_l)), ]

ggplot(spainmax) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = franceCoast_l)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(spainrest) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Here I merge both LINESTRINGs with `st_union()`:

```r
# Merge

joined <- c(st_geometry(spainmax), st_geometry(franceCoast_l)) %>%
  st_union()


ggplot(joined) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

And now the task is to reassamble the small parts of Spain and apply the `lwgeom::st_split()` approach.

```r
# Ok, we are ready
# Get the rest of pieces of Spain

join_end <- st_union(joined, st_geometry(spainrest))

ggplot(join_end) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
bbox_all <- st_bbox(joined) %>%
  st_as_sfc()

polygon_joined <- bbox_all %>%
  lwgeom::st_split(join_end) %>%
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

#Polygons on position 2 and 3 need to be removed (visual inspection)
polygon_end <- polygon_joined[-c(2:3)]

ggplot(polygon_end) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: one last question:

Comment: (too late :D) A last question: spainurl <- "https://geo.vliz.be/geoserver/wfs?request=..." how do you do to use it ? I went on the geo.vliz.be and I did not find how did you used it, and I like it. Could you tell me how do you choose your region etc ? Thanks :)